# How to make a n:1 multiple tags system for a blog & which database schema is better?

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I'd like to create a tagging system for a blog and it's articles; *as stackoverflow's tagging system for it's question.*

### database structure

```
Table  - articles
Fields - article_id, article_title, article_content

Table  - article_tags
Fields - tag_id, article_id, tag_name
```

If an user enters tags in the input; let's say they enter the following tags:

1. `php`
2. `mysql`
3. `database structure`

I'd like to understand how to convert the following tags into an array and then insert each tag into a new value line as followed.

```
article_Tags

    tag_id | article_id | tag_name
       1          1          php
       2          1          mysql
       3          1          database structure
```

I'd like to have PHP break each tag down by commas, and insert it separately into a new row value.

How do I accomplish this? Do I need a foreach and explode() to break down each tag?

---

**Does the following table structure seems better than the above?**

```
Table - article
Fields - article_id, article_title, article_content

Table - article_tags
Fields - article_id, tag_id

Table - tags
Fields - tag_id, tag_name
```

If so how do I go by entering each tag into the database, do I need explode() as well as the first table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second structure is better. You store way less data that way.

The easiest is to create a CRUD for the tag table, to display those tags on your create post form and on submit insert everything into your article & article_tags table accordingly.

But you could also let the user directly create tags from the post form with a bit of JavaScript then insert those tags into the db before inserting into article & article_tag.

Don't forget you'll need to check for duplicates either way. No sense in having 10 different `php` tag per your example.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still brain-storming(mind designing) how to take each step accordingly, PHP code wise. Do you have skype?

Comment: Sorry don't have the time right now. But add me @titiomm if you still need help later

Answer (score 1):

This is called a many to many relation, and it's better to create an intermediary table.

**You may ask why?** Well, let's try out an example and see which one is better. Let's say you have 100 articles, with 3 tags each, and 30 unique tags.

**First version:**
`article_tags` will contain a total of 300 entries, which means that each tag name is duplicated on average 10 times.

**Second version:**
`article_tags` will contain the same 300 entries, but instead of having the tag name appear 300 times, it will appear only 30 times in the `tags` table.

So the second version has less duplicate content, so you should go with that.